Unity.UI не могу использовать аргументы
по глупости импортировал в проект ассет с готовой игрой из 2019 года, после чего появилась проблема, что не работает часть функций из библиотеки Unity.UI, например onClick или image
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class RepeatSequenceGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button[] colorButtons; // Массив кнопок
    public Text feedbackText;

    private List<int> sequence = new List<int>(); // Секретная последовательность
    private List<int> playerSequence = new List<int>(); // Введенная игроком последовательность
    private int sequenceLength = 3; // Начальная длина последовательности
    private int currentStep = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        StartGame();
        foreach (Button btn in colorButtons)
        {
            btn.onClick.AddListener(() => OnColorButtonClick(btn));
        }
    }


Вроде как удалил все файлы, которые как либо были причастны к тому ассету, так же удалил Temp,Logs и obj по совету GPT, но проблема осталась

Это не Button из UnityEngine.UI. Ты создал класс Button с полем onClick, у которого тип object.
